# What method would I use to see if slashes are a certain position in a string?

Tags: java

I need help figuring out how to check to see if the slashes are correctly entered in a date:
mm/dd/yyyy

I have used:

```
int index1 = date.charAt(3)
int index2 = date.charAt(6)
```

But this is giving me a out of bound range?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to retrieve chars from positions that don't exist in your string?

Comment: It means that someone put shorter string than you expected and you ended up with trying to read character at position which doesn't exist (it is out of range/bounds). Check `length()` of string first, or use some regex like `\d{2}/\d{2}\d{4}` to check if string matches it.

Comment: For it to be `MM/dd/yyyy` format there has to be exactly 10 characters. Check this first and your charAt methods will work.

Comment: This approach is terribly brittle. It would fail (when index-corrected) on `fr/ee/beer`.

Comment: What does validating the presence of the slashes accomplish? Also, if you're going to parse the date I'd recommend using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Please clarify your question. As you can see from the above comments, your question could be understood as "slashes have to be at the correct place (2 and 5)" or "need to parse a Date that has a certain format (e.g. MM/dd/yyyy)".

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are getting an out of bounds exception, then the string is too short to have the index `3` or `6`.  Test the length of the string with the `length()` method before checking specific indexes.  If it's too short, then it doesn't have a slash in the position that doesn't exist.

Second, indexes in Java start with `0`, so given the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, you would be looking or slashes at indexes `2` and `5`, not `3` and `6`.